How could warfare be kept using pike and shot like tactics for 700 years?
In real life the pike and shot tactics were only dominant for 150-200 years or so before the pike largely disappeared and it become mostly just musket. However, could the era of pike and shot warfare have been made longer?
In this case, for the drastically longer period of 700 or so years. In this case, pike and shot warfare shouldn't extend into the early industrial age of technology, technology should still be around the level of the start of the industrial era when people move away from pike and shot. What happens to technology before or during this extended pike and shot era i don't really care about aside from that. Technology could stagnate, the pike and shot era could start earlier relative to other technologies, or anything.
The most important things are that pike and shot style warfare be dominant for 700 years, and that pikes disappearing should happen around the same time as the start of the industrial revolution, with technology relatively unaffected past that point. Beyond that, it can be anything other than magic.

Is this on Earth or another planet/parallel dimension? The problem being on Earth (as is and was) it's arguably not feasible (for a range of reasons) for what you want to happen. If you give people some wriggle room to change certain basic geological/geographical/historical parameters? Then maybe.

Could you tell us a bit about the geography, politics, international diplomatic stuff and relative levels of technology?

@mon "Beyond that, it can be anything other than magic"

@Escapeddentalpatient. i haven't figured that out for this era yet, this is my starting point for extending my world's history back further than the mid 19th century type era.

I think you need a world where shots can only be fired non-explosively, to slow down the development of firearms. A reason for that could be societal taboo, or because the explosion could not be contained, and would be suicidal. Explosive firearms would have to wait until they are able to invent a totally contained explosion to propel the bullet.

The pike did not mostly disappear and it bec[a]me mostly musket: it turned to a bayonet. The true novelty was the same individual switching from musketeer to pikeman over the course of the battle: in a way, the basic tactics would remain the same until after WWI. Please clarify which specific aspect of the Renaissance pike&shot tactics you wish to preserve over 700yrs.

I don't see how you can prevent something as simple as the bayonet from being invented. Maybe just handwave it, just like Westeros has been stuck in the middle ages for a millenia.

@FrançoisJurain Which basic tactics? I don't recall there being a lot of pike bayonet squares in WWI.

@Ray here's to refresh your memory: the ANZAC's impression of a bayonet square in Gallipoli. https://media.cnn.com/api/v1/images/stellar/prod/150423211618-13-anzac-british-1915.jpg?q=w_2451,h_2421,x_0,y_0,c_fill

@Ray you don't recall, possibly because the more vocal proponents had been silenced with machine guns even before it was time for you to get near the battlefield. The French general staff thought highly of the bayonet in 1914, much less in 1917.

@FrançoisJurain I suppose I was thinking of the mixed pike and shot formations where the pikes were responsible for stopping cavalry charges, but you're right; there existed other pike tactics and that photo does bear some resemblance.

@Ray the basic tactics I have in mind is to have both ranged and melee weapons issued to the men of the elementary combat unit. Initially, the two sorts were handled by different individuals, trained differently: meaning that at any given moment, half the manpower was only useful as a deterrent, not as an agent of ground dominance. It looks like this is the specific trait the OP wants to retain over 700yrs.

The lesson from WW1 is that against machine guns, the pike-like weapon is more a nuisance than a resource: this was not yet obvious against 19th C. artillery, at least to general staffs in Europe. Dunno about the US Civil War and the asymmetric, colonial wars.

@FrançoisJura with this question the idea is to have the pike and shot era cease around the same time as the early industrial era starts. the technology for machineguns is like 120 years past the early industrial era.

@OT-64SKOT Then the solution is to delay the discovery of the explosively propelled missile until the early industrial era. Have everyone fight with crossbows and airguns, problem solved.

@FrançoisJurain while that's kinda the same i was very much looking for pike and shot with the shot being fairly normal muskets.

There are many explosive chemicals. Get them using a worse one than gunpowder. (because they haven't discovered gunpowder). Maybe a substance that degrades over a few days, making premade ammo impractical.

I find the twin concepts of "early industrial age" and "no decent muskets" hard to combine. How about a combination of these:

The climate in the industrializing area is quite wet. There are both random and 'scheduled' rains, e.g. "hereabouts you get afternoon rains in the spring, and all-day rains in summer." It takes advanced firearms to work reliably in the glop, yet how do you get advanced firearms if primitive firearms are not very practical? Pikes and steel crossbows work, augmented by musketeers who work hard at keeping their powder dry.
The social tradition calls for a citizen militia bringing their own arms, and there is emotional attachment to being a 20th-generation pikeman and yeoman farmer. There were no desperate wars where a levee en masse overturned tradition, just border squabbles with pike-and-shot regiments and rebellions using what was at hand.
There are native animals with nasty barbed tentacles who could reach a man even if they are spitted on top of a bayonet. The pikes have crossbars, similar to a boar spear, to keep them at bay. So every farm has a couple of pikes and a couple of lads trained to use them sort-of-cooperatively, with one pinning the animal down and the other slaying it.


it doesn't have to be continuously in the early industrial age, it should just be the early industrial age around when the pike and shot era ends. IRL the pike and shot era lasted to around 1700 which was also when early industrialization bega .

Pike and shot tactics were never dominant in general. They enjoyed two relatively brief periods of popularity, in two very different historical periods, in two limited geographical areas.

The original pike and shot formations were the Macedonian phalanges. (Or phalanxes? I'm going with the classical language plural here.) A sarissa is a pike; the shot part were peltasts, slingers and archers. The phalanges reigned supreme over the eastern part of the classical world for maybe 200 years, until they met the Roman heavy infantry.

The second time, pike and shot formations were introduced in the Renaissance, with some sort of primitive fire arms instead of javelins, slings, and bows. The Thirty Years' War saw the last attempts to use conventional pike and shot formations.


In both cases, pike and shot formations proved to be ineffective against opponents which knew what they were doing and refused to play by the pike and shot rules. The problem is that a pike and shot formation is very rigid; it simply cannot maneuver except to move slowly in a straight line, it cannot fight at all except on relatively flat open ground, cannot do anything against a fortified opponent, and is vulnerable to disruption by basically any kind of tactical surprise.
During the hundred fifty years or so when pike and shot formations were popular in post-medieval western Europe, Western and Central European armies were routinely beaten by the Ottomans, who took Belgrade in 1521, destroyed the Hungarian army in 1526, sucessfully defended Algiers in 1516, 1519, and 1541, and eventually made Emperor Charles V agree to pay an yearly tribute of 30,000 gold florins. (That is about 100 kilograms of gold, which would be worth about 8 million US dollars nowadays. Not a lot of money for Charles V, who had already accumulated a debt of about 3 tonnes of gold to the Fuggers and other creditors, but the important thing is that the Christian emperor agreed to pay tribute to the Muslim emperor.)
Fortunately the Ottomans were bad at naval warfare, and lost the decisive Battle of Lepanto in 1571 against the Western European fleet of the Holy League, which balanced the fortunes of war. It was the last major battle between oar-powered ships.

Could one argue that the infantry square of the Napoleonic age (thereabouts) is also a sort-of pike and shot formation, with the pike being also the shot, i.e., musket with attached bayonet.

The Swedish Pike-and-shot formation were the formation between 30 years war and napoleon, replacing the "Spanish Square", which was somewhat similar. See the Battles of Breitenfeld. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Breitenfeld_(1631) - Tilly used the "Tercio" square, the swedes went to use cavalry strikes and a different formation around that time, proving very effective.

@DohnJoe One definitely could.  Firearms had become good enough that the cavalry had largely discarded their armor in favor of greater mobility, at which point 6 feet of musket and bayonet, while not as good as a ten-foot pike, is "good enough" since, while the cavalry will win with a fully-committed charge, the horses and men in the front of the charge will definitely get skewered if they press the attack that hard. There were some heavy cavalry units that kept much longer lances and some armor for busting up infantry squares, but they were much more expensive to outfit and train.

Have fast growing grasses be very common
Your world has a lot of fast growing grasses which will quickly grow up to the height of a man. This makes guns much less effective and ambushes much more easy, as very few areas will be open plains.
To prevent charges and melee attacks, pikes remain a very popular weapon.
Have natural body armour.
Some sort of natural organism produces a silk that's very effective at stopping bullets. A natural kevlar vest. It is less effective against slashing weapons. This means guns are notably less effective than melee weapons.
Have major losses by armies that try to convert to use guns
Have the characters talk about some serious losses and defeats by idiots who relied on guns over pikes. It should be a well known and common fact that guns aren't effective on their own.

Hopefully it's a wet planet year-round, or the wildfires could be epic.  And a tool of war in their own right, which could have great implications for world building and story telling.  "We have guns, so we wait for the right wind and weather, and then light the grass ahead of our advance."

Your third point is an effect, not a cause.  If a gun-heavy army loses a battle against a comparable opponent, it's a sign that it's not yet time to switch.

@Mark I believe the intent is to have it be a sociological cause. That is, there were several notable early failures (when the tech wasn't quite developed) which embedded themselves in the general consciousness enough that no one bothered reconsidering them as the tech developed. Or perhaps the failures even resulted in the tech not being developed -- gunsmithing is not an easy occupation to take up with 1500s tech levels, and there might be very few if no army bothers paying for them. Fewer gunsmiths mean a slower pace of development.

Yeah. If gunsmithing is seen as a failure, you can imagine pike and armour technology would develop faster.

@Mark: It can also be that the first battles fought with it were fought be commanders who used it poorly, were broadly incompetent at their jobs, were up against military geniuses, were fighting in a terrible situation (e.g. ambushed in a canyon by archers with elevation and cover), or some combination thereof. People aren't always rational, and the loss could be blamed on the technology, ignoring all the other issues.

Have the planet lack easily accessible iron
Sadly you can't avoid a planet to have iron, due to some fancy thermonuclear restrictions that make iron "fusion ash" as well as "fission ash", but not letting people living on its surface to get iron with relative ease should at least force them running with bronze, copper, stone (obsidian) tools for longer. When they develop a "shot" in form of a crude cannon, it'll be made of bronze, not last long enough to survive more than several battles, and as a result would kind of look as a dead end; but the "end" efficient enough to wield.
Also with proper geologic formation and water levels you can make it so that all the iron is located on the seabed or below, thus "technically" the planet will have accessible iron, but practically it would all be too hard to acquire, compared to Earth.
Note also that having no iron will prevent humanity from being able to control any processes going at 1700K or above, even if they would be able to attain that temperature. This might have unpredictable consequences on the world's history, down to the civilization to never attain enough energy to transition to industrial era.
Make the planet wet
Like, tropical weather across the warfare zone, a small continent or some lowlands interspersed with channels, covered with lush greenery, allowing humans to largely rely on foraging, as well as delaying plowing and agriculture. This would cause the gunpowder of any sort, be it natural-based or coal-based, to get wet too fast, limiting reliance on gunpowder-based weaponry. Also it takes different skills and weapons to properly fight amidst jungles, so in a mostly-jungle world the pike and shot tactics could easily degrade to "sword and shot". Shots will be present anyway, check Aztecs' "atlatl" spear-thrower, with the visible range of less than ten arms' lengths you might not succeed to react with a bulky blast cannon before you would already be fighting in melee.
As an extra, you can remove coal from either easy or complete availability. To my knowledge, the coal deposits have formed due to the biosphere's inability to eat lignine, the main component of wood, but once a fungus species mutated and gained that ability, in about 1000 years it spread over all the globe and new coal deposits ceased forming due to being eaten prior to getting pressurized. Having no coal would not just limit transition to pure gunpowder-based weaponry on its own, but also has potential to block the humanity's advance to industrial era, as they would have to somehow get access to a reliable source of electricity to run their industries instead of just moving things with coal.

I like the idea of not having access to coal would limit access to iron.  Iron can be produced from burning wood instead of coal but it would be much more expensive because wood is useful building material and trees produce fruit we can eat, burning the trees for iron means destroying that resource for food and/or shelter.

@MacGuffin: We've been making wootz steel, not merely iron, using a charcoal furnace for the heat, and bamboo and leaves for the carbon source, for ~2500 years. India was not exactly shy on people who might benefit from more trees, but hey, money and weapons beat trees any day of the week.

I think you can even take a carrot and stick approach to the no iron-approach by giving an alternative. Maybe there is no metal, but at the same time a common local species of hardwood tree could be just strong enough to allow it to be used for low powered musket barrels, but not high powered cannons or anything with a higher rate of fire.

@mlk better use bamboo-like barrels for one-shot "shots", can them in reusable pseudo-barrels made from copper/bronze (stone should get shattered) to prevent personnel injury, and voila, a ready-made ammo prototype, but such a weapon could not be used for anything better than a shrapnel shot IMHO, due to the "cannon" deforming from ammo firing.

Be isolated from much of the rest of the world. It also helps to have smaller, low-intensity conflicts.
This happened historically in Japan. During their big civil war in the 16th century, at the end they mostly used Yari (similar to a pike) together with matchlock arquebuses they got from the Portuguese and learned to manufacture themselves.
Then at the end of the civil war, they closed themselves from the rest of the world. When the Americans first arrived in the second half of the 19th century and made them stop their isolation, the Japanese were still using 16th century matchlock firearms.
The development of the flintlock led to the pike and shot becoming obsolete, as now guns could be equipped with bayonets, which was not very practical on matchlocks. If gun technology stays at the matchlock level, then the pikes remain viable.
If your world is not an alternate history on real life Earth, just make the world smaller. If it is set on Earth, have it set on an island like Japan which is isolated from the rest of the world for centuries. Japan was peaceful during the Tokugawa era, this also played a role in weapon technology not being developed further, so if you want to have war, have smaller local wars between rival factions, instead of wars between big empires.

You actually propose peace, not isolation :P

There is no absolute solution to this problem that does not depend on breaking the laws of physics. If you have firearms, then eventually they will become good enough to make any other kind of personal weapons obsolete, simply due to the energy that can be packed into the shot.
However, there are some minor things that can be done to the 'verse that would at least delay the demise of the pike, such as:

Vastly improved armor metallurgy. if for some reason, their ability to produce high quality steel outpaced the progress of firearms, it is possible that they could have developed armor that could withstand the musket shots and be all but impervious to bayonets. This would extend the necessity of polearms, pikes, and warhammers to deal with the "superknights" in bulletproof armor.

Much better horses> strainign plausibility, but it is possible, if however improbable, that the horses in this scenario had been bred for war for far longer than in our world, and the warhorses the "superknights" use are even faster, bigger and more durable than normal, being able to blitz through a hail of musket shot, while clad in heavy barding armor. Again, pikes would be needed to stop them.

Alternative mounts: maybe the cavalry now uses rhinos, elephants, mammoths or some other giant beasts that are near buleptroof and can wear tank-like armor?

Mechanized cavalry. Maybe a much simpler industrial revolution arrived earlier, and the cavalry can mount very simple and crude trucks, motorcycles, or armored wagons? Can't stop one with bayonets, but a wall of extra-strength pikes just might.

Inversely, make the muskets crappier. Maybe your world had some kind of global even that caused most of its sulfur to become organically bound (sulfur-eating bacteria??), or buried too deep underground? If sulfur is hard to get, gunpowder would either be much more expensive or contain less sulfur and thus be much weaker. Or maybe whatever affects sulfur causes gunpowder to decay fast, so by the time your infantry is ready for battle, their muskets pack only as much of a punch as a quail shooter.

Super-pikes. Turns out there is this really, really weird type of bamboo in your world that produces perfectly pike-sized stalks, that somehow manage to be extremely lightweight and more durable than any hardwood (maybe it naturally produces carbon nanotubes? or if not that, then maybe some super macroprotein, or insanely strong cellulose monofiber?). This allows pike formations to be far more robust, pikes longer, and yet easier to maneuver. But by the same token, it also makes cavalry lances far stronger even at twice the length, leading to arms race between pikes and lances that bayonets cannot win. Hells, maybe the super bamboo can be made into crappy musket barrels: it would make the creation of weak firearms far cheaper, but ensure they can never quite get the sufficient power and muzzle velocity.


Why not combine it into one: there is this species of super bamboo that, due to its durability, is wildly used around the planet for everything, including super-pikes, crappy, but extremely cheap "muskets" and even bulletproof armour. The secret to its durability is that it soaks in sulfur from the environment, and turns it into a components of a super strength fiber. The fiber cannot be easily converted back into a sulfur resource though, so the bamboo destroys the supply. A side effect is that if this super-bamboo is fed to livestock, such as horses, it causes them to grow much larger, with much stronger bones.

I'm not asking pike and shot warfare remain dominant forever, just quite a bit longer. The main issue is making it so that whatever the change is that allows pike and shot to be dominant for so long shouldn't massively affect warfare after the pike and shot era ends

Hence why I suggested the "bamboo" idea. Once the designs for muskets (and ultimately, rifles) are advanced enough, the "bamboo technology" becomes obsolete, because frankly, a shot from a rifle goes through just about anything you can field for battle, and after it was invented, the "gun vs armor" competition was always won by gun. So the Bamboo Age would really be quite short

"Vastly improved armor metallurgy" is quite a contradiction. Key breakthroughs in firearms revolve around better metallurgy. It makes weapons more precise, smaller and more powerful. As others noted, you need non-metal armor.

Such formations didn't really disappear for some time. What happened to them, essentially, was muskets being upgraded to do "pike" and "shot" simultaneously by means of bayonets (and better muskets), rendering pikes redundant.
If you want the pikes to stick around, your basic objective is to make them remain relevant. In other words, you need muskets to remain relatively marginal against cavalry and for cavalry to remain a sufficiently great threat to require pikes. There's a few ways of doing that, depending on how much you're willing to tinker with your world.
Stronger Cavalry
If cavalry can resist musket-shot and shorter bayonets, longer pikes with greater stopping power and bracing capability become necessary. If your smiths are able to make armor for horses strong enough to resist musket-shot, it's probably also strong enough to trample soldiers relying only on bayonets, especially if the cavalry are lancers. You'd end up with cataphract heavy cavalry, which would be fairly expensive to maintain and have limited endurance, but the charge of such cavalry would simply overpower a musket line.
If you're open to going the fantasy route, your options widen. Lizard-based mounts with tough scales, for instance, might naturally deflect or stop most small-arms projectiles. Stopping a cannonball is simply implausible, but if they can withstand grapeshot, they'd be especially terrifying. Also, the bayonets might be too weak and/or too short to be effective against an armored hide, forcing a reliance on long sturdy pikes (likely needing crossbars) or perhaps halberds to stop their charge. Alternatively, you might have a mount with Kevlar-like hide that's better at keeping out projectiles than pointy spears: if a musket and bayonet isn't long enough for the needed purpose, pikes become vital.
As a more mundane matter, one could also simply try larger cavalry contingents. If horses suitable for combat training are more numerous, less expensive, etc., cavalry will obviously be a more potent threat.
Weaker Muskets
If the muskets don't advance far enough, they won't be able to do everything. If the flintlock musket is never invented or is otherwise unfeasible (as Trish's answer notes, a shortage of flint is one possibility for the latter case), you're stuck with matchlocks, which have some downfalls. Needing a continuously burning match in the vicinity of gunpowder is an obvious safety hazard if, say, refilling a powder horn (or anywhere near the army's powder storage), so men armed with these are as good as doomed in an ambush or other surprise attack. They're also subject to the weather, as a rainy day makes matchlocks nearly useless by soaking the powder and/or preventing the match from burning.
Bayonet design is also a factor. Plug-based bayonets prevent the musket from being fired, which is an obvious liability if the bayonets can only be attached at the last moment. If socket-based bayonets are never developed in a reliable form, bayonets become a lot less practical. You end up in a similar position if your muskets, for whatever reason, can't be made sturdy enough to consistently eat the impact of a cavalry charge without breaking: I'm not sure about the plausibility of this last idea, but it's a thought.
If you'd prefer to favor defensive answers, you can always consider alternative developments in armor. If there's some sort of Kevlar-like armor that your society has developed and made widespread, muskets become significantly less effective at stopping armored foes in general.

The "kevlar" of the time was silk, and there were bullet-proof vests made from it once it became cheap enough. So that might be an option. I'm not sure where the idea that matchlocks have a slower reload time than flintlocks came from. They really don't, it's a very similar mechanism. What they don't have is the ability to be ready at a moment's notice 24/7 since the match has to be kept burning.

@Perkins I might have misread something, in that case. I'll adjust the answer accordingly.

So the matchlock era did also go along with lower quality manufacturing of both the guns and the ammunition as well as lower quality gunpowder.  Plus I don't think paper was cheap enough for pre-measured cartridges for most of it. So all that could affect the historically recorded loading times. But there's nothing inherent to the mechanical operation of the matchlock that would make it slower to load other than having to puff on the match a couple times to make sure it's hot if you haven't used it in a while.

A disease or natural disaster "resets" civilization with regularity, just as people are about to claw their way into better technology.  This keeps happening until there is enough built up knowledge, built up immunity, or some random event breaks the cycle and human civilization can advance into an industrial age.
Consider a path through space that has a lot of asteroids going by, and every 100 years or so the orbit of the planet and the orbit of these asteroids coincide such that meteor showers kill a bunch of people, cause fires and destruction, and generally scatters people to where they have to resort to hunter-gatherers for a while.  With each cycle bits of books, oral history, pieces of infrastructure, or what not, survive so it's not a complete reset but it does mean people aren't likely to retain the ability to produce weapons more advanced than pointed sticks for some time.
Consider a disease that spreads quickly through a population once people have developed enough to have something of an urban society, a time when people start to pack in more tightly so diseases can spread.  The disease kills off a bunch of the population, the survivors scatter about to subsistence farming or whatever, then when things get well enough again that towns develop then disease thins people out, scatters them without much in technology and the cycle repeats until immunity or technological prevention develops.
Consider some kind of insect or other predatory creature that lies dormant for long periods, when active it stings people or something to make them forgetful, loopy, or simply dead.  With this periodic chaos technology gets reset until, as above, some kind of immunity or technology develops to break the cycle.

I think we should start with why we even had a pike & shot formations.
So we got this new awesome weapon -  arquebus. It's way better than bows or crossbows, but still have a lot of issues. Loading time is way too long and arquebuses needs protection from enemy infantry and cavalry that could engage in melee combat.
So to prolong pike & shot we just need to remove factor that allowed infantry to wield only muskets.
Bayonet is not invented
Spear was a best war weapons for ages. Bayonet allowed muskets to act like a spear when needed! It was a great deal, as now musketmen formation can protect themself from cavalry or melee infantry. Of course it time it evolved into bayonet vs bayonet fights for infantry, but we still can get our lesson - no bayonets means longer live for pike & shot.
Flintlock musket is not invented
There's a second side of the coin that allowed for line infantry to exists and let to dissolution of pike & shot. Muskets appeared - loading time was way shorted and firepower increased. A volley was invented - all muskets shot all at once, decimating both enemies morale and lives. If unwieldy, long-time loading arquebuses are still primary weapon, we need some guys to protect them.

The problem with your requirements is that people reached the early industrial age without the flintlock. That is, steam engines and sewing machines, but no decent springs?

It could be for a multiple of reasons other than technological, cultural, religious etc...I do agree with those mains two points.

So the hard part is going to be that a pike is just a long, sturdy stick with a sharp thingy on the end, and a musket or similar is a long, sturdy stick that throws things.  As soon as you get the bright idea to put a sharp thingy on the end of the long, sturdy stick you instantly find that your formations can now have both twice as many pikemen, and twice as many musketeers...  That's rather a winning combination.
The only way I see to keep people from doing that would be to make it so that the pikes really need to be exceptionally long to be effective.  Maybe instead of warding off horses, it's scaly lizard creatures and you really need multiple, overlapping rows of spearpoints to have a good chance of breaking their charge.  If their scales are sufficiently thick, then the big, slow bullets of the blackpowder age might have a difficult time penetrating them, so you can't afford to do without at least a couple ranks of dedicated pikemen.  Even if spears won't hurt them much either and it's just to physically hold the blighter back for a few more seconds while everyone tries desperately to put a bullet through its eye.
Then just put off the invention of nitrocellulose and nitroglycerine for a couple hundred years and you'll be getting probably close enough.

Change the geology.

Your world is more tectonicly active and/or has less livable land  mass than Earth. As a result it has only one major continent with the greater part of the rest being large island chains like Japan and Indonesia. This lead to a situation where historically various civilizations from the continent tended to dominate those on lesser landmasses close to their borders though the sheer scale of their resources and numbers.

Eventually, after a long period of struggle centuries ago one single Empire arose that managed to dominate and eventually conquer all others on the main continent. By the time it did so its technology level had risen to roughly the level of pike and shot but only by default because it was forced to adopt the technology and tactics of it's various opponents to win (defeat is a great teacher). This empire is also authoritarian, innately conservative and caste based with its ruling elites imposing the tenets of it's equally strict, conservative religion upon all conquered subjects. There are also strict laws governing who can perform what tasks and trades. (There are lots of cultural examples from Earths history to draw inspiration from.)

Given access to the resources of the entire continent it eventfully expands across the world and subjugates all other land masses. With no external threats, no more people to conquer and only the occasional revolt to suppress? There is almost zero pressure to industrialize further or advance  military or any other technology further (beyond perhaps sailing & naval architecture). And importantly? No 'free thinking' class of intellectuals or entrepreneurs to invent or finance innovation in  general. The military itself? Is now smaller and less influential than it was during the age of conquest and has largely been relegated to performing garrison duties, suppressing banditry and piracy and crushing peasant revolts. Finally, with no other cultures or opponents left to force further innovation and developments in military technology in general? It stagnates at the level of pike and shot. The world needs a great disruption of some kind before progress can resume.



Space aliens like watching people fight like 16th century Europeans for reasons known only to the space aliens, and will air-drop the appropriate weapons before battle and a payment of valuable moveable goods after victory to any warband willing to do so. Consequently, pike and shot tactics were popular until weapons technology advanced so much that it was completely suicidal to do so, leading to the ratings collapse of "The Pike and Shot Show with Glograth the Undying" season #719.

Gunpowder smoke contains poison
In your world, sulfur or saltpeter is always produced mixed with toxic impurities. These impurities are not easily removed even in the process of making gunpowder. Upon firing, they scatter around, causing pain in the shooter's lungs or eyes.
Because the smoke harms the shooter, shooting in close formation like line infantry is suicidal. Soldiers shoot while maintaining spatial intervals, but such formations cannot withstand cavalry charges. Therefore, pikemen always support them.
As gas masks are developed or impurity removal technology advances, the effects of the poison decrease. And 700 years later, your history will merge with real history, and armies battle in while scattering large amount of gun smoke. The era of pikemen is over.

gunpowder smoke already is toxic, but this would just advance the invention of some sort of gas-mask by a few hundred years.

There is no good supply of flint
Pike-and-Shot formations came up around 1500 when firearms were mass-produced. The pike part of the formation was required to shield the reloading gunners from getting mowed down by Hakkapalita or other cavalry.
The end of the Pike-and-Shot formation came with the advent of the Flintlock, which made reloading the guns not just faster, but also joined the pike to the gun in the shape of the bayonet. The Flintlock, paper cartridges and other advances thus lead directly to line infantry.
But this change requires an ample supply of flint. Without flint, there can't be flintlocks, keeping the technology at slower matchlocks, and making the presence of pikemen to shield units necessary.
There's no war
The one driver of innovation is war. If there is no war, technology stagnates, like the gun technology of the Tokugawa shogunate: there was no need to advance in the peaceful Edo Period, leading to about 250 years of stagnation. Do note however, that the standard formation was not a tercio or Pike-and-shot, but long lines of gunner units in between spearmen flanks to deter the few cavalry units.

" There's no war "  There's still going to be hunting and improvements in firearms means improvements in getting valuable protein into the diet.  If we assume most meat comes from domesticated cattle instead then there would still be a desire to improve the accuracy, reliability, and so forth of ranged weapons to protect cattle from predatory animals.  It's also possible for firearm technology to skip over the flintlock to percussion caps.

The purpose of a dedicated pike instead of just using a bayonet, is primarily to deal with cavalry. A bayoneted firearms is going to do little for you against a lance. Against early bows or firearms, a cavalry could charge and kill an unprotected group without exorbitant losses
The better power, range and reloading speed of later firearms as well as better tactics is what made this no longer possible. It would be very difficult to have other aspects of technology advance to the point of allowing the industrial revolution without having firearm technology also advance. A steam engine needs large, precise cylinders, pistons, and springs. A flintlock  uses a lot of the same technology and tools and is just much easier to make.
In order to make the pike stick around, you need to maintain the advantage cavalry had against unprotected firearm formations, and the alternative to making firearms worse, is making cavalry better. Either better horses or better mounts, I like armoured rhinos.
In terms of the overall impact on technology afterwards, this is also pretty much ideal because once steam engines exist, they will still be much better than super horses or rhinos.

Note:  Length of musket with bayonet: 6'6".  Length of common cavalry lances: between 6'6" and 9'.  A pike is definitely better. but by the time the cavalryman is striking the infantryman, the infantryman is at least in reach to stab his horse in the face. So that's just enough deterrent to make a bunch more muskets that are useful all the time preferable to lugging around a bunch of pikes that are only useful when the cavalry actually charges. The counter from cavalry would be to bring back more armor, but then they're slower and easier to shoot.

Frame Challenge, they WERE used for about 700 years
The problem with your assumption is that "pike and shot tactics" where just a single iteration out of many similar military doctrines that date all the way back to 950AD.  Military doctrine naturally changes a bit with every generation; so, sometimes we use a term to refer to a specific iteration of that doctrine or as the doctrine as a whole, like how "legionary" tactics could describe a 200-700 year time span depending on how specific your meaning is.
So if we look at the age of pike and shot simply as the combined use of firearms and spears, you actually see it begin around 950AD in China.  The Chinese mounted small cannons at the end of thier spears (called fire lances) that they would fire into the enemy formation before charging them with thier spears.  This was in effect an identical tactic to the latter strategies invented by the Swiss that you are talking about.  This lasted in China until about 1250 at which point armies switched to more specialized hand cannons, but still fought in a wide range of combined arms tactics that utilized some variation of spears and guns.  Spear and gun combined arms also became instantly popular in Europe as firearms entered the scene, it was just how formations were used that took time to develop into the exact thing that we think of as "Pike and Shot".

Delay the discovery of gunpowder or just make saltpetre prohibitively expensive.

Then where does the "shot" come from?

As before. slings and arrows are unaffected. Guns could exist but if gunpowder is not readily available then guns would be rare enough that they would not impact warfare tactics. Without cannon, the tightly packed formations required for pike warfare would still be viable.

@Joachim defensive pikes plus projectile throwers as a military formation predates gunpowder.  And the only reason it stopped being used with gunpowder weapons is that the bayonet made dedicated pikemen unnecessary.  Other projectile throwers are far less suited to attaching bayonets.

@Perkins Pike and shot generally (mostly and arguably originally) refers to the combination of pikes and muskets/arquebuses. Moreover, the OP speaks of how afterwards it became "mostly just musket". Hence my question.

@Perkins - Sorry but that is just not correct. Pikes are a stand off weapon effective against cavalry, so protecting the ranged weapons (slings, bows, muskets etc.) behind. A musket once fired becomes a club, putting a bayonet on it just makes it a sharp club.

@PaulSmith Putting a bayonet on it makes it a short spear.  The Brown Bess for example was 58 inches long, and mounted a 21 inch bayonet. Not as good as a true pike, but good enough for an infantry square to stand-off cavalry effectively, at least long enough for those toward the center to have time to reload and take potshots at the cavalry until they give up. Cavalry breaking an infantry square armed with muskets and bayonets requires long lances. Such cavalry were used by some (Polish) armies, but they require a much higher degree of training to wield such long weapons in formation.

@Joachim The shot part does primarily refer to firearms in terms of linguistics, but the tactics themselves were merely a new weapon added to what was previously done with pikes and archers, and previous to that with pikes and slingers as far back as the Macedonians. Part of the development of the English longbow comes from the English and Welsh using big blocks of pikes to stand off cavalry and then trying to out-range each others' archers and pelt the other side to death.

Pike-and-Shot is the term for any formation that started with the Tercio and similar formations around 1500 and ended with the mass-fielding of flintlock rifles with bayonett.

Thank you for the negative votes. Regardless of how you choose to define 'shot', the end of pike and shot tactics (which is the core of the original question) occurred when the tight formations required of pikemen became vulnerable to cannon. Delay cannon (by making gunpowder impracticable) and you delay the end of the pike formations.

@PaulSmith  That is a fair point. Although I'd suggest that the final nail in the coffin was the advent of cheap, repeating firearms, which removed any need to use pikes for standing off cavalry, along with cannon making grouping up in big area targets dangerous. Not sure how to delay that independently of firearm technology in general though. Maybe delay the discovery of smokeless powder. Black powder fouling puts some serious constraints on loading mechanisms.
